# yticklabels Cut Off in Pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, label

I'm making a simple horizontal stacked bar plot:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'firstBox':firstL,'secondBox':secondL,'thirdBox':thirdL})
ax = df.plot.barh(stacked=True)
ax.set_title("My Example Plot")
ax.set_yticklabels(labels=['A label this long is cut off','this label is also cut off])
plt.show()
```

but the values on my ytick labels are being cut off. If I increase the width of the returned plot window, I can see slightly more of them, but I need to stretch the window well past the width of my monitor to see the entire label. Is there a way to just push the plot to the right to include my long labels?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should try this:

```
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams.update({'figure.autolayout': True})
```

Comment: When creating multiple graphs, this will only update the last plot created. Is there a way to make this the default property on all plot?

Answer (score 5):

In case you are using savefig, `bbox_inches='tight'` is an option that automatically try to figure out the tight bbox of the figure.

Comment: It would be preferable if you provided an explanation of the code you have posted. It will help other members of the community who will visit this post as well. A well-explained answer will attract up-votes, and hence, establish your credibility.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ax.get_figure().tight_layout()` or `plt.gcf().tight_layout()`. This will fix the figure layout.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I've recently come across this as well. Here is some sample code that will expand the plot region to include all axis ticks. Note the bit that does the expanding of the plot area is `bbox_inches='tight'`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

names = ['Name 1','Name 2','Name 3','Name 4','Name 5','Name 6']
y1 = []
y2 = []
for name in names:
    y1.append(np.random.rand())
    y2.append(np.random.rand())
df = pd.DataFrame({'First ': y1, 'Second ': y2}, index=names)
ax = df.plot.bar(rot=0)
ax.set_xlabel("X Axis")
ax.set_ylabel("Y Axis")
ax.set_title("Sample Plot")
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=30, ha="right")
fig = ax.get_figure()
fig.savefig("Fig_Name", bbox_inches='tight')
```